# LibGDX Model Instance color is not passed to Vertex Shader

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, glsl, shader

I'm stuck with the following problem for a couple hours now:

In LibGDX, I want to render a ModelInstance with a custom shader like this:

```
modelBatch.render(modelInstance, shader);
```

Regarding the shader, I call

```
shader = new CustomShader();
shader.init();
```

in the game's create() method.

The CustomShader class looks like this (cut down to the big methods):

```
public class CustomShader implements Shader {

    ShaderProgram shaderProgram;
    Camera camera;
    RenderContext renderContext;

    @Override
    public void init() {

        shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram(
                Gdx.files.internal("core/assets/Shaders/VertexShader.glsl").readString(),
                Gdx.files.internal("core/assets/Shaders/FragmentShader.glsl").readString()
        );

        if (!shaderProgram.isCompiled()) {

            throw new GdxRuntimeException("Shader program inside water shader is not compiled yet:\n" + shaderProgram.getLog());
        }

        System.out.println("Shader compiled successfully");

        ShaderProgram.pedantic = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void begin(Camera camera, RenderContext renderContext) {

        this.camera = camera;
        this.renderContext = renderContext;

        shaderProgram.begin();
        shaderProgram.setUniformMatrix("u_projViewTrans", camera.combined);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Renderable renderable) {

        shaderProgram.setUniformMatrix("u_worldTrans", renderable.worldTransform);
        renderable.meshPart.render(shaderProgram);
    }
}
```

For the vertex shader, I copy-pasted some code, that is supposed to be a simple pass-through shader:

```
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;

uniform mat4 u_worldTrans;
uniform mat4 u_projViewTrans;

varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {

    v_color = a_color;

    gl_Position = u_projViewTrans * u_worldTrans * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
}
```

The thing is, the ModelInstance (whether is being made by calling createBox, or by constructing it tri-by-tri with a ModelBuilder) is always rendered flat-red.

The fragment shader does not seem to be the problem; if I hardcode v_color inside the vertex shader like

```
v_color = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
```

the model gets rendered in green as it should.

What I cannot achieve, is the model being rendered in the color defined by its material.
It seems, that the java code doesn't pass the color down to the vertex shader.

It would be really great if one of you knew the answer; I'm fighting with that problem for ages now.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

As I only need the shader for ModelInstances of a single model that only has one base color, I don't really need the color, nor the material. Instead, I declare the color as a uniform vec3 inside the vertex shader. This kinda works for the moment, but it is not, what I really want.

So if anybody knows, how the vertex shader can get the color of the rendered Renderable, I'm still open for solutions :)

Comment: *"It seems, that the java code doesn't pass the color down to the vertex shader."*  - So where do you specify the array of color attributes?

Comment: I create the model instance by simpy calling "modelInstance = new ModelInstance((new ModelBuilder()).createBox(1, 1, 1, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN)),
                VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal));".

Comment: I can add "VertexAttributes.Usage.ColorPacked" to the statement, that actually makes everything white.